# Org-mode lags in highlighting source

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, org-mode

I'm using org-mode to maintain my programming notes. This means I have lots of source code blocks, as follows.

```
#+begin_src <language name>
    <code>
#+end_src
```

One thing I've noticed is that when I write the #+end_src, emacs doesn't color the source code as such. Yet, if I quit emacs and reopen the notes file (or force a refresh with the Org->Refresh/Reload->Refresh setup current buffer menu entry) the source is colored grey if I'm using the GUI or green if I'm using emacs in the terminal. Is this an inherent limitation of emacs, or am I doing something wrong in setting up my code blocks that's preventing emacs from going back and recoloring the source code that I've entered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm getting the same issue when testing and writing out the code by hand (however C-w C-y on the entire block does fontify it).

However if I use either yas-snippet (the snippets bundled with emacs24-starter-kit) and then expand `src`

```
#+begin_src <language>

#+end_src
```

or `sb`

```
#+source: <title>
#+begin_src <language>

#+end_src
```

or use the org built-in template expansion (See: [Easy Templates](http://orgmode.org/manual/Easy-Templates.html#Easy-Templates)) and `<s` for source code blocks the fontification works perfectly (although I do get `org-mode fontification error` echoed to my mini-buffer, so perhaps there is something that could be fixed).  Once the fontification works it does seem that it will continue working.

It may be worth bringing up to the org-mode mailing list to see if any of the developers would have an answer as to whether this is by design or a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the C-w C-y suggestion. It's certainly easier than forcing org-mode to refresh the entire buffer. I also see that `<s` works, but in my case I don't see the fontification error.

Comment: The fontification error may be related to the theme I'm using. I'd have to test without it to see. (Although come to think of it I didn't see it today on my linux laptop, only on Windows when checking yesterday, so it might be OS related somehow.